# Cannot collapse a responsive menu in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am new to website development so I am testing with some responsive menu to see how it works in Wordpress. I have selected this menu and it works perfectly in the demo. Yet, when I apply the code to my site, the menu bar cannot be collapsed. **class="navbar-collapse collapse show"** the **show** in this class cannot be removed properly. [You can see it while inspecting the page : https://gttutor.com/test/ May I know how should I fix it? Thanks!

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="padding-right: 0px;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                
        </div>
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-mainbg" style="
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-logo" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fas fa-bars text-white"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="padding-right: 0px;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <div class="hori-selector"><div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div></div>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-address-book"></i>Address Book</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-clone"></i>Components</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Calendar</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>Charts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-copy"></i>Documents</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script>
          // ---------Responsive-navbar-active-animation-----------
        function test(){
          var tabsNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent');
          var selectorNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent').find('li').length;
          var activeItemNewAnim = tabsNewAnim.find('.active');
          var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = activeItemNewAnim.innerHeight();
          var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = activeItemNewAnim.innerWidth();
          var itemPosNewAnimTop = activeItemNewAnim.position();
          var itemPosNewAnimLeft = activeItemNewAnim.position();
          $(".hori-selector").css({
            "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px", 
            "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
            "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
            "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
          });
          
          $("#navbarSupportedContent").on("click","li",function(e){
            $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
            var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
            var itemPosNewAnimTop = $(this).position();
            var itemPosNewAnimLeft = $(this).position();
            $(".hori-selector").css({
              "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px", 
              "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
              "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
              "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
            });
          });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
          setTimeout(function(){ test(); });
        });
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
          setTimeout(function(){ test(); }, 500);
        });
        $(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
          setTimeout(function(){ test(); });
        });
    </script>
```

Method from Rank:

```
( function test( $ ){
          var tabsNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent');
          var selectorNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent').find('li').length;
          var activeItemNewAnim = tabsNewAnim.find('.active');
          var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = activeItemNewAnim.innerHeight();
          var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = activeItemNewAnim.innerWidth();
          var itemPosNewAnimTop = activeItemNewAnim.position();
          var itemPosNewAnimLeft = activeItemNewAnim.position();
          $(".hori-selector").css({
            "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px", 
            "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
            "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
            "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
          });
          
          $("#navbarSupportedContent").on("click","li",function(e){
            $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
            var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
            var itemPosNewAnimTop = $(this).position();
            var itemPosNewAnimLeft = $(this).position();
            $(".hori-selector").css({
              "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px", 
              "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
              "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
              "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
            });
          });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
          setTimeout(function(){ test(); });
        });
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
          setTimeout(function(){ test(); }, 500);
        });
        $(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
          setTimeout(function(){ test(); });
        }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `navbar-toggler` button doesn't have any toggle class code. Instead, there is an empty setTimeout() defined. Try to change it like this.

```
$('.navbar-toggler').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#navbarSupportedContent').toggleClass("show");
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sar! Do you mind editing my code so I could follow? Do you mean the last few lines? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Ozgur Sar already gave the correct answer, but there might be reasons why it is not working:

It is very likely that the error "$ is not a function" appears in the Console. Although Wordpress has jQuery natively, the function sometimes must be wrapped as follows to work:

```
( function( $ ) {
    /* your code ... */
}( jQuery ) );
```

So your code can look like:

```
( function( $ ) {
      var tabsNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent');
      var selectorNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent').find('li').length;
      var activeItemNewAnim = tabsNewAnim.find('.active');
      var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = activeItemNewAnim.innerHeight();
      var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = activeItemNewAnim.innerWidth();
      var itemPosNewAnimTop = activeItemNewAnim.position();
      var itemPosNewAnimLeft = activeItemNewAnim.position();
      $(".hori-selector").css({
        "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px", 
        "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
        "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
        "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
      });
      
      $("#navbarSupportedContent").on("click","li",function(e){
        $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
        var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
        var itemPosNewAnimTop = $(this).position();
        var itemPosNewAnimLeft = $(this).position();
        $(".hori-selector").css({
          "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px", 
          "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
          "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
          "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
        });
      });
      
      $('.navbar-toggler').on('click', function(e) {
          $('#navbarSupportedContent').toggleClass("show");
          e.preventDefault();
      });
}( jQuery ) );
```

This should work.

I'm not using the timeout functions. If you want to make a smooth transition, try using CSS transition properties to make it look nice.

---

**About adding javascript to wordpress**

A more reliable way to do it would be putting it in a seperate file (maybe a `js` folder inside of your theme folder) and enqueue it with the dependency of jQuery (because the code will not work, if jquery is not loaded correctly). This can be in the `functions.php` of your theme:

```
function gttutor_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gt-tutor.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gttutor_scripts' );
```

Comment: Hi @Rank Thanks for your reply. I didn't post the code properly to stackoverflow so it looks like commented out and actually the script should be working! I will try your method first and will come back to you later! It takes some time for me to digest it. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried editing like what you said for the first method but seems it doesn't work. I will now test the second one!

Comment: Instead of doing the first one, you could also replace all the `$` with `jQuery`. You are using jQuery syntax. So I wanted to make sure that the code is interpreted the right way. Did you check your browser console (right click -> inspect) if there is an error saying `$ is not a function` ? The second one is just a improvement to keep your theme structure clean.

Comment: It used to work well even for jQuery code as long as i have href the required files in header like jquery.mis.js something like that. Just checked there is no error when I inspected the site, only the "aria-expanded" keep remain in "true" whenever i click the menu button :(

Comment: Well, now you did not define the `test` function, so there should be an error... you only define the test-function because of the timeout. As your code is in the edited question of yours, get rid of the document ready settimeout stuff and try again. :)

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Ummm I am a bit confused if you don’t mind could you help editing my code so i can study based on your solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear, sorry if I confused you ;)

Comment: Here's a little update! I read through the inspect and realize that it is due to a css command from my Wordpress theme, .show {display: block!important;}. Regarding this situation, how can I override it?

Comment: Ok. Why not use another class like 'visible' or 'custom-show' if the show class is already used in your theme. You can easily toggle other class in your javascript.